# Displaying the texts printed in div to show as paragraph

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-8

I have an issue in displaying various sentence which is taken from DB and each printed inside a div. I need this div to shown back to back as in a paragraph. The problem I am facing is that if the sentence is longer, even though when there is space in the previous line, it falls to next line.
https://jsfiddle.net/Laz8t8hq/

```
<div class="paragraph">
   <div class="col">It is a long established fact</div>
   <div class="col">that a reader</div>
   <div class="col">will be distracted by the readable content of a page </div>
   <div class="col">when looking at its layout.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour for `display: inline-block` -  it behaves like a block, so when its contents exceeds any given space available for it to occupy, it collapses to the next line.

To have it *wrap* in the manner intended, use `display: inline`

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Laz8t8hq/1/)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.paragraph {
  width:500px;
}

.paragraph .col-inline {
  display:inline;
} 

.paragraph .col-inline-block {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Before</h3>

<div class="paragraph">
  <div class="col-inline-block">It is a long established fact</div>
  <div class="col-inline-block">that a reader</div>
  <div class="col-inline-block">will be distracted by the readable content of a page </div>
  <div class="col-inline-block">when looking at its layout.</div>
</div>

<h3>After</h3>

<div class="paragraph">
  <div class="col-inline">It is a long established fact</div>
  <div class="col-inline">that a reader</div>
  <div class="col-inline">will be distracted by the readable content of a page </div>
  <div class="col-inline">when looking at its layout.</div>
</div>
```